# The target average value in Decision Trees is calculated using mean or median?

Tags: machine-learning, mean, decision-tree, median

What **measure of average** is considered for calculating the **target average value** in Decision Trees? Is it **mean** or **median**? Also, if it is mean, then, why is median not considered since it is a better measure of center in the presence of outliers?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It is mean and not median. This is because calculating median requires the data to be sorted, and so the process becomes more intensive. The cases where median is a better measure of center is when the data has skewed data points. However, in Decision Trees the data points that are part of the leaf are most likely to not have the outlier because the outlier would land in other leaf.